# How to update a nested immutable map

Tags: scala, clojure, immutability

I'm trying to find a cleaner way to update nested immutable structures in Scala. I think I'm looking for something similar to `assoc-in` in Clojure. I'm not sure how much types factor into this.

For example, in Clojure, to update the "city" attribute of a nested map I'd do:

```
> (def person {:name "john", :dob "1990-01-01", :home-address {:city "norfolk", :state "VA"}})
#'user/person
> (assoc-in person [:home-address :city] "richmond")
{:name "john", :dob "1990-01-01", :home-address {:state "VA", :city "richmond"}}
```

What are my options in Scala?

```
val person = Map("name" -> "john", "dob" -> "1990-01-01", 
             "home-address" -> Map("city" -> "norfolk", "state" -> "VA"))
```

Answer (score 5):

As indicated in the other answer, you can leverage `case classes` to get cleaner, typed data objects. But in case what you need is simply to update a map:

```
val m = Map("A" -> 1, "B" -> 2)
val m2 = m + ("A" -> 3)
```

The result (in a worksheet):

```
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(A -> 1, B -> 2)
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(A -> 3, B -> 2)
```

The `+` operator on a `Map` will add the new key-value pair, overwriting if it already exists. Notably, though, because the original value is a `val`, you have to assign the result to a new `val`, because you cannot change the original.

Because, in your example, you're rewriting a nested value, doing this manually becomes somewhat more onerous:

```
val m = Map("A" -> 1, "B" -> Map("X" -> 2, "Y" -> 4))
val m2 = m + ("B" -> Map("X" -> 3))
```

This yields some loss-of-data (the nested `Y` value disappears):

```
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> 1, B -> Map(X -> 2, Y -> 4))
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> 1, B -> Map(X -> 3))  // Note that 'Y' has gone away.
```

Thus, forcing you to copy the original value and then re-assign it back:

```
val m = Map("A" -> 1, "B" -> Map("X" -> 2, "Y" -> 4))
val b = m.get("B") match {
  case Some(b: Map[String, Any]) => b + ("X" -> 3)  // Will update `X` while keeping other key-value pairs
  case None => Map("X" -> 3)
}
val m2 = m + ("B" -> b)
```

This yields the 'expected' result, but is obviously a lot of code:

```
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> 1, B -> Map(X -> 2, Y -> 4))
b: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(X -> 3, Y -> 4)
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(A -> 1, B -> Map(X -> 3, Y -> 4))
```

In short, with any immutable data structure when you 'update' it you're really copying all the pieces you want and then including updated values where appropriate. If the structure is complicated this can get onerous. Hence the recommendation that @0___ gave with, say, [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle).

Comment: could you explain how the "loss of data" is happening in the nested example?

Comment: @Samar Updated the answer. Specifically, the 'Y' in the nested map disappears.

Comment: You could have done: val m2 = m + ("B" -> Map("X" -> 3, "Y" -> 4)) to keep the Y value.

Comment: @Samar Yes, but assuming what you want to update is `X`, and you don't know `Y` (or if it even exists) but want the data structure to retain it, you have to go through extra work. That is the last bit of code I included.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. The last para in your answer sums it up well.

Comment: @Samar Glad to be of help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to upvote answers that were helpful to you and 'accept' the best answer to your questions. This way people will be more incentivized to help you out in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Scala is a statically typed language, so you may first want to increase the safety of your code by moving away from any-string-to-any-string.

```
case class Address(city: String, state: String)
case class Person(name: String, dob: java.util.Date, homeAddress: Address)
```

(Yes, there are [better alternatives](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time) for `java.util.Date`).

Then you create an update like this:

```
val person = Person(name = "john", dob = new java.util.Date(90, 0, 1),
  homeAddress = Address(city = "norfolk", state = "VA"))

person.copy(homeAddress = person.homeAddress.copy(city = "richmond"))
```

To avoid this nested `copy`, you would use a lens library, like [Monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle) or [Quicklens](http://www.warski.org/blog/2015/03/quicklens-traversing-options-and-lists/) (there are many others).

```
import com.softwaremill.quicklens._
person.modify(_.homeAddress.city).setTo("richmond")
```

Comment: In particular, `Map[String, Any]` is not going to be fun in Scala.

Comment: @Ryan: isn't the presence of "Any" a bad sign in any collection type signature? List[Any] etc.

Comment: Yes, any time the type system has to infer `Any`, you've probably made a mistake.

Comment: @0__: I see. Thanks - this answer brings clarity on how I should be thinking about this in a statically typed language.

Comment: Why is nscala-time better? Isn't it based on JodaTime which people are moving away from? I thought the new library standard going forward was `java.time`? @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers nicely sum up the importance of correctly modelling your problem so we don't end up having to deal with Map[String, Object] type of collection.

Just adding my two cents here for a brute force solution utilizing the quiet powerful function pipelining and higher order function features in Scala. The ugly asInstanceOf casting is needed because the Map values are of different types and hence Scala treats the Map signature as Map[String,Any].

```
 val person: Map[String,Any]  = Map("name" -> "john", "dob" -> "1990-01-01", "home-address" -> Map("city" -> "norfolk", "state" -> "VA"))

 val newperson = person.map({case(k,v) => if(k == "home-address") v.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]].updated("city","Virginia") else k -> v})
```